# Partial match search every key's value in a document with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, database, nosql

I'm working on a project for a client that wants to store information about trucks, trailers, and other types of equipment in their database. After comparing and contrasting relational databases with solutions like MongoDB, I've found that the flexibility of a schema-less type of database combined with the way the data is going to be accessed by the application makes Mongo the better choice (see the schema below). There's only one issue that I'm having, and that is how to implement an autocomplete search. The salesmen want to be able to search any key (model, year, price, odometer reading) and get a list of all the documents that match that result. For example, a salesman might search for "Freightliner" and expect to get back the example document that I attached below.

```
{
  "_id": "E-123456",
  "created_by": "2",
  "status": "available",
  "properties": [
    {
      "active": true,
      "version": 1,
      "last_modified": "2014-06-10 00:51:02",
      "category": "heavy duty truck",
      "subcategory": "conventional w/ sleeper",
      "manufacturer": "Freightliner",
      "model": "CST12064ST-CENTURY 120",
      "year": 2009,
      "price": 39950,
      "wholesaleprice": 0,
      "odometer": 129000
    }
  ],
  "images": [array of image urls],
  "salesman_chat": [array of chat subdocuments],
  "created_at": "2014-06-10 00:51:02",
}
```

I was able to get something like this working by using `db.equipment.ensureIndex({"$**":"text"})`, and then searching it like this: `db.equipment.find({$text:{$search:"freightliner"}})`. The problem that I'm having is that since this is acting like an autocomplete, I want to start displaying results as soon as they begin typing, and **I'm unable to figure out how to do partial or wildcard matches.** For example, I want a search for "E-12" to return all of the documents with an _id of  "E-12*".

My question is, I'm not sure if it's possible to use something like $regex with Mongo's $text search. If it is, how do I do that?

I've looked around stackoverflow for a while and some of the solutions have suggested creating a separate collection with an _id reference and an array holding the values of all of the source document's keys (like a list of keywords to be searched). Is this the only way I can do this while keeping the structure of my data the same and without using other database solutions? Should I look into something like Elasticsearch or Solr?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to search for partial words, a text index is the wrong tool to use, because it only indexes complete words.

When you want to match partial words, you will have to use normal indexes on the fields where searching makes sense. You can then search the individual fields with regular expressions. However, keep in mind that regular expressions only benefit from indexes when they begin with the begin-of-string anchor `^`.